# Keycloak - Find eccess_token after authentification

Tags: session, keycloak, access-token, bearer-token

In an angular application (with backoffice in C#), i use Keycloak with identity provider (to Azure AD) for authentification.
After login, the user is redirect to my application, but i can't find the access_token for call my APIs.
Keycloak target my application with this url : http://localhost:4200/alertes#state=c81d3a0f-78bc-4d6e-99bb-b3a1cba67c24&session_state=021848ba-8a22-4e88-b0a5-dbadb9ca414f&code=4ec91dfe-392f-48e7-b9ef-5306b828f9d0.021848ba-8a22-4e88-b0a5-dbadb9ca414f.34d8304c-f94d-41de-9b26-98ebdaee05da

Can i get the access_token (by requested keycloak's Apis by example) with the returned properties (state, session_state, code) ?

Or use anothenr méthod (header, parameter, cookie, mapper, ...)

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you learn the basics of OAuth2 and OIDC and how the so called "Auth Code Grant" works. Additionally, you should use some library for your ecosystem, in case of Angular, e.g. https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular